# How to make the pathTransition start randomly from the right or the left when the metod with the path inside is called?

Tags: java, javafx, path

Here is the code of the method that creates and plays the path transition.

```
void moveAereo()
{    
        //ImageView transition
        PathTransition aereo = new PathTransition();
        PathElement[] path = new PathElement [5];
        path[0]=new MoveTo(-60 ,30);
        path[1]=new LineTo(800 ,100);
                path[2]= new LineTo(700,50);    
                path[3]= new LineTo(750,30);
        path[4]=new ClosePath();

        Path pista = new Path();
        pista.getElements().addAll(path);
        aereo.setNode(getAereo());
        aereo.setPath(pista);
                aereo.setAutoReverse(true);
        aereo.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        aereo.setDuration(new Duration(5000));
        //ciclo infinito
        aereo.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        aereo.play();
 }
```

Comment: After the animation has been started, should it still run randomly or start moving in the opposite direction, when it reaches the end of the path?

Comment: It should start moving in the opposite direction when it reaches the end.Its a condition of the problem . Thank you for the help

Comment: The speed of the animation should be choosed randomly anytime the method is called . IT is another condition too I just readed about .:/

Answer (score 0):

Just determine the rate at which you want to play the animation at random and allow negative rates. Depending on whether the rate is positive or negative, play the animation from the end or from the start.

**Example:**

```
private final Random random = new Random();
private static final double MAX_RATE = 5;
private static final double MIN_ABSOLUTE_RATE = 0.5;

private double getRandomRate() {
    double magnitude = (MAX_RATE - MIN_ABSOLUTE_RATE) * random.nextDouble() + MIN_ABSOLUTE_RATE;
    return random.nextBoolean() ? magnitude : -magnitude;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Change");

    Rectangle node = new Rectangle(10, 10);

    PathTransition aereo = new PathTransition();
    PathElement[] path = new PathElement[5];
    path[0] = new MoveTo(-60, 30);
    path[1] = new LineTo(800, 100);
    path[2] = new LineTo(700, 50);
    path[3] = new LineTo(750, 30);

    path[4] = new ClosePath();

    Path pista = new Path();
    pista.getElements().addAll(path);

    aereo.setPath(pista);
    aereo.setAutoReverse(true);
    aereo.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    Duration duration = Duration.seconds(5);
    aereo.setDuration(duration);

    aereo.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    aereo.setNode(node);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        double newRate = getRandomRate();

        aereo.setRate(newRate);
        if (newRate > 0) {
            // play from beginning
            aereo.playFromStart();
        } else {
            // play from end
            aereo.playFrom("end");
        }
    });

    Pane root = new Pane(btn, node);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 200);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem of the speed but im having problems with the postions .playFrom("end ").I dont really know how it works tried everything but it doesnt start from the end. If you know any method that can make tha animation start  Upper or down when the method is called it wold be very helpful . Thanks

Comment: @ErInd [According to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#getCuePoints--) the cue point `"end"` should be positioned at the end of the animation (and it worked this way, when I tested it), but you could also replace `aereo.playFrom("end")` with `aereo.playFrom(aereo.getTotalDuration())`. Whether the animation plays forward or backward depends on the sign of the rate.

Comment: .thank you for the answer but i copied your code in both ways and the plane starts only from the start . Maybe the problem is that the sign of the rate never becomes negative or you tried a main while what im doing is calling a method  for the path . I firs thought it was the problem at aereo.play() affter if and else but I tried removing it and nothing changed . I have no idea :/

Comment: I tried your code too with the rectangle in a main class and it only start from the left never changes positon . So i dont know why the vlaue of  Rate never goes negative :/

Comment: @ErInd Oh sorry, there are multiple cycles used there. should be `getCycleDuration` not `getTotalDuration` but of course it only starts from the left since both ends of the path are on the left...